# Running a VS2010 project in monodevelop. Monodevelop "unable to find 'resgen' tool"

Tags: c#, winforms, monodevelop

I'm sorry if this question has been asked. The only answer I could find was that it "is a known problem and is being worked on", in a post from 2009.
I was working on a c# project that uses Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2010 but I have now migrated to linux (mint version 16). I installed monodevelop (v3.0.3.2) and whenever I attempt to compile the program it is "unable to find 'resgen' tool" in form1.resx.
Am I missing something or is linux incompatible with windows forms?

Here is all the version information for my copy of monodevelop:

`MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
Installation UUID: 9f803f0d-c437-451c-a84a-38de77bf46e4
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2) (64-bit)
    GTK 2.24.20
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Build information:
    Git revision: 7bf6ac0ca43c1b12703176ad9933c3484c05c84c-dirty
    Build date: 2012-08-24 05:44:11+0000
Operating System:
    Linux
    Linux UPSTAIRS-PC 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Make sure that you have `mono-complete` installed first.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, works now.

Answer (score 0):

To work on Mono related development, it is recommended to install `mono-complete` which contains all bits you might need,

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mono-complete

To this specific question, I think `mono-devel` should be at least installed,

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/mono-devel/filelist

The default Ubuntu/Mint installation should have only installed a few of the core Mono bits, which is not enough.